# Specify conditions on ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have two entities: An `Element` is associated to one `Diagram`. A `Diagram` can have several `Elements`.

```
@Entity
public class Diagram 
    @ID
    private UUID uuid;

    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    private Date update_date;
```

I can have several versions of my diagram. But the most recent `update_date` gives me the current version of a diagram.

```
uuid(PK) |      id | name |update_date         
--------------------------------------
BLOB     |  UUID-A | foo  | 2018-03-19 
BLOB     |  UUID-A | bar  | 2018-03-21
```

When I call `element.getDiagram()`, Hibernate should search for the most recent Diagram on `Element.diagramId=Diagram.id`.

```
@Entity
public class Element
    @ID
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Diagram diagram;
```

For example :
I want the state of the diagram on the 2018-01-20. The SQL query will look like that.
So it will give me the diagram with the name `foo`.

```
select d.* 
from element e 
join diagram d 
 on e.diagramId=d.id and d.updated_at < '2018-01-20'
order by d.updated_at desc
limit 1;
```

### What I've tried

1. Put `@ManyToOne` over the `Element.diagram` field. But Hibernate automatically creates an unique constraint on `Diagram.id`. Which is not possible in my case, because I can have several versions of a diagram with the same id (which is not the primary key).
2. A `@ManyToMany` is not possible either. Because Hibernate will create a `unique constraint` on `Diagram.Id`. Which is not possible because we can have several entries in `Diagram` corresponding to all versions of a diagram.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is diagramId is Element class?

Comment: `diagramId` of Element corresponds to `id` of Diagram. It's not the primary key of Diagram.

Comment: Just posted, hopefully, this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create diagramId for reference, Spring will do for you.

All you need is to update latest diagram id to element table when you create a new diagram. In this way you will not have to create reference keys(diagramId, id etc)

You can solve this by:

Element.java

```
@Entity
public class Element {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String elementName;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= { CascadeType.MERGE })
  @JoinColumn(name="diagram_id", nullable = false)
  private Diagram diagram;
```

Diagram.java

```
@Entity
public class Diagram {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String diagramName;

  private Date update_date;
```

Test

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/elements", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Element> getElements() {
    return elementRepository.findAll();
}
```

Result

```
[
 {
"id": 1,
"elementName": "Element 1",
"diagram": {
         "id": 1,
         "diagramName": "Diagram 1",
         "update_date": "2018-03-21T08:31:00.000+0000"
           }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. But I already tried that. Because of the `ManyToOne`, Hibernate creates `unique constraint` on `Diagram.id`. So, I can't have several versions of the a diagram. Moreover, with your attempt, how do you handle the fact of getting the most recent diagram based on the `updated_date`?

Comment: @Keysersoze - when you create a new diagram. You create new diagram you will get diagram id right? then update that diagram id to element table on column diagram_id. Once done, you diagram_id would be the latest diagram related to the element.

Comment: @Keysersoze - to confirm you should make id is diagram table auto increment.

Comment: I prefer using a UUID than an auto incremented integer. Because the diagram.id must not change. I have to be able to retrieve all the versions of my diagram thanks to its diagram.id. What I am trying to do is possible with MySql. It's just a Hibernate issue.

Comment: @Keysersoze in that case when you create you diagram you just set uuid and pk key in diagram table. and use element.setDiagram(createedDiagramObject)... that's it.

Comment: @Keysersoze if you want i can walk through step by step. lets join chat.

Comment: With this solution, how do you retrieve the most recent Diagram from an Element entity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167286/discussion-between-keysersoze-and-vk321).